# WebGL is not supported (vpython no me funciona como debería)

Tags: python, vscode, opencv, webgl

estaba probando la librería vpython en python y ejecuté este código:

```
from vpython import *
ball=sphere(color=color.red)
while True:
    pass
```

La idea era que se abra una pestaña del navegador (porque es donde se ejecutan las cosas de opencv) y que mostrara una esfera roja. En cambio, lo que aparecía era una página web en blanco, sin nada. Cuando inspeccioné la página y fui a la consola me di cuenta que aparecía este error: [image: error que aparece en la consola al inspeccionar la página web donde debería aparecer la esfera])

[image: página web completa, con el error de la consola al inspeccionar la páigna]
Dice que no soporta WebGL, pero no se que es.

Después busqué en mi navegador chrome://gpu, y me salió esto:
[image: Estado de la grafica en chrome://gpu]

Puede ser que porque no tengo habilitado WebGl 2 no me funcione? O será porque los drivers de mi gpu son muy viejos?

Por si acaso aclaro que tengo windows 10 de 64bits, python 3.10.4 y la última versión de visual studio code. Mi procesador es el i5 2500 (con gpu integrada).

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Listo, ahora si está más claro y completo

Comment: Ejecuté únicamente las primeras 2 líneas de tu programa y salió la esfera roja. Para el problema que mencionas encontré un [artículo](https://appuals.com/fix-webgl-is-not-supported/) que en general dice que el error `WebGL not supported` puede ser por que tus driver no estén actualizados, tu navegador no esté actualizado, tu hardware no lo soporta o estás utilizando Windows XP (Entre otras cosas)

Comment: Si, esa página vi cuando estaba buscando información sobre el problema, estaba todo bien, pero no pude instalar los drivers, me dice que son los más nuevos. Intenté descargarlos manualmente, pero no encontré nada. Muchisimas gracias igual